# How do I make an infinite, repeating sequence in clojure?

Tags: clojure, sequence

I want to take a sequence or vector and create an infinite, looping, lazy version of it. This is what I tried:

```
(def test-seq '(1 2 3))
(take 5 (repeat test-seq))
```

And I got

```
((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))
```

When what I wanted was

```
(1 2 3 1 2)
```

I know this works

```
(take 5 (flatten (repeat test-seq)))
```

but that seems a bit unsatisfying and flabby. I'm assuming re-structuring a sequence of sequences is expensive but I may well be wrong :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `cycle`:

```
(take 5 (cycle '(1 2 3))) ;; => (1 2 3 1 2)
```